# Pouring water using Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, recursion, breadth-first-search

I am trying to solve the pouring water problem from [codechef](http://www.codechef.com/problems/POUR1) using scala. The problem statement is as follows:

> Given two vessels, one of which can accommodate a liters of water and
>   the other which can accommodate b liters of water, determine the
>   number of steps required to obtain exactly c liters of water in one of
>   the vessels.
>
> At the beginning both vessels are empty. The following operations are
>   counted as 'steps':
>
> ```
> emptying a vessel,
> filling a vessel,
> pouring water from one vessel to the other, without spilling, until one of the vessels is either full or empty.
> ```
>
> Input
>
> An integer t, 1<=t<=100, denoting the number of test cases, followed
>   by t sets of input data, each consisting of three positive integers a
>   (the number of liters the first container can hold), b (the number of
>   liters the second container can hold), and c (the final amount of
>   liters of water one vessel should contain), not larger than 40000,
>   given in separate lines.
>
> Output
>
> For each set of input data, output the minimum number of steps
>   required to obtain c liters, or -1 if this is impossible.
>
> Example Sample input:
>
> 2
>   5
>   2
>   3
>   2
>   3
>   4
>
> Sample output:
>
> 2
>   -1

I am approaching this problem as a graph theory problem. Given the initial configuration of containers to be `(0, 0)`, I get the next state of the containers by applying the operations:

`FillA`, `FillB`, `PourAtoB`, `PourBtoA`, `EmptyA`, `EmptyB` recursively until the target is reached.

My code is as follows:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Queue

def pour(initA:Int, initB:Int, targetCapacity:Int) {
    var pourCombinations = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[(Int, Int),Int]
    val capacityA = initA
    val capacityB = initB

    val processingQueue = new Queue[(Int, Int, Int, Int)]

    def FillA(a:Int, b:Int) = {
      (capacityA, b)                    
    }
    def FillB(b:Int, a:Int) = {
      (a, capacityB)
    }   
    def PourAtoB(a:Int, b:Int): (Int, Int) = {
      if((a == 0) || (b == capacityB)) (a, b) 
      else PourAtoB(a - 1, b + 1) 
    }
    def PourBtoA(b:Int, a:Int): (Int, Int) = { 
      if((b == 0) || (a == capacityA)) (a, b) 
      else PourBtoA(b - 1, a + 1)
    }
    def EmptyA(a:Int, b:Int) = {
      (0, b)
    }
    def EmptyB(a:Int, b:Int) = {
      (a, 0)
    }

    processingQueue.enqueue((0, 0, targetCapacity, 0))
    pourCombinations((0, 0)) = 0


    def pourwater(a:Int, b:Int, c:Int, numSteps:Int): Int = {
        println(a + ":" + b + ":" + c + ":" + numSteps)

        if((a == c) || (b == c)) {return numSteps}

        if(processingQueue.isEmpty && (pourCombinations((a,b)) == 1)) {return -1}

        //Put all the vals in a List of tuples
        val pStateList = scala.List(FillA(a, b), FillB(a, b), PourAtoB(a, b), PourBtoA(b, a), EmptyA(a, b), EmptyB(a, b))       

        pStateList.foreach{e =>
          {
            if(!pourCombinations.contains(e)) {
              pourCombinations(e) = 0
              processingQueue.enqueue((e._1, e._2, c, numSteps + 1))
            }
          }
        }   
        pourCombinations((a, b)) = 1
        val processingTuple = processingQueue.dequeue()
        pourwater(processingTuple._1, processingTuple._2, processingTuple._3, processingTuple._4)

     }
     val intialvalue = processingQueue.dequeue()
     pourwater(intialvalue._1, intialvalue._2, intialvalue._3, intialvalue._4)
}
```

There are a couple of issues with this, first of all I am not sure if I have my base cases of my recursive step set-up properly. Also, it might be that I am not using the proper Scala conventions to solve this problem. Also, I want the pour function to return the `numSteps` once it is finished executing. It is not doing that at the moment.

It will be great if somebody can go through my code and point out the mistakes with my approach.

Thanks

Comment: It might be interesting to you that there is already similar question on code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10224/pouring-water-my-first-scala-code/10233

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting. I will go over the post and try to process it.

Comment: I still lack the scala maturity to fully comprehend what was posed as the solution on code review. It will be great if somebody can go over what I have here tell me what I am missing and what I can do better.

Comment: It is not homework. This is my attempt to solve problems with an algorithmic bent using scala with an intention to learn more about algorithms and scala. I am pretty sure the collective scala expertise of SO would see through the pitfalls of the snippet that I presented.

Comment: Also, right after I presented my snippet, I have tried to articulate a few of the things that I think might be wrong with my code.